# Can I read the Tokyo Ghoul RE manga if I have watched the first 2 seasons of the anime?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I have seen the first season of *Tokyo Ghoul* and a few episodes of *Root A* and I want to know if this is enough to read the *Tokyo Ghoul RE* manga. I have heard that *Root A* doesn't fit into the story of the manga, so should I watch it before I read *RE* or not? I'm also not sure if you can watch the first season of *Tokyo Ghoul* before *RE*, or do you have to read it in the manga?

Answer (score 1):

*Tokyo Ghoul: Root A* heavily diverges from the original manga, which you've heard correctly. The first *Tokyo Ghoul* season does an *okay* job of covering its manga counterpart, but there are things that were skipped over or different. Since *RE* is the sequel to *Tokyo Ghoul*, if you go into it having only seen the two anime seasons, you'll be a little confused due to some of the plot points you'd have missed from the manga.

If you want to experience *RE* in full understanding, you might want to read the previous manga first. However, if you don't mind some confusion, it's ultimately up to you. Hope this helped!